# Splitting HTML file using AWK

Tags: html, awk

I was wondering if it's possible to split a HTML file into seperate .html files using awk? I'd like to look for the pattern:

```
<div class="post">
```

And when it finds this create the new file for each instance, I've tried to compile the command but can't get it working? My file is called working.html and this is what I got back from the command I've constructed.

```
awk '/<div class="post">/{x="F"++i;}{print > x;}' working.html
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it's bombing out because `x` is not initialized and can't be used as a filename until it is first set on a `<div>` line.

One way to fix that is to add a BEGIN pattern to initialize it.

```
BEGIN {
  x = "F0"
}

/<div class="post">/ {
  x = "F" ++i
}

{ print > x }
```

Comment: thanks for the reply! Do I just run type this straight into the commmand line? Sorry I'm new to awk.

Comment: Except for the *BEGIN,* I haven't changed your program, I just reformatted it. So to run it your way, just use `awk 'BEGIN{x="F0"}/<div class="post">/{x="F"++i;}{print > x;}' working.html` ... or run it my way with `awk -f prog.awk working.html`

Comment: I get back awk: F17 makes too many open files
 input record number 254, file working.html
 source line number 1, it should only make around 100 files?

Comment: is there a max line size? It seems to have stopped on line 254 out of 1516?

Comment: Sounds like you should close the old file when you make a new one. `awk 'BEGIN{x="F0"}/<div class="post">/{close(x);x="F"++i;}{print > x;}' groceries.html`